# Why can I not create a project on angular even though I've installed everything I need?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am currently learning Angular, and have installed Nodejs and Angular Cli on my computer. However, after going through so many tutorials online, I can never seem to create a new project despite repeating the steps before to make sure I hadn't done anything wrong. I am extremely confused on what to do, I've included [two screenshots of what I've done so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmnGH.png)

[2nd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdQxx.png)

If anyone can help that would be much appreciated!

Comment: You seem to have several fundamental misunderstandings about what the commands you're attempting to run are actually doing or supposed to do. Can you share, in your own words, what exactly you would expect each of these to do when run? It seems to me you're trying to change into a directory (repeatedly) that doesn't exist, why not create it first? What exactly did you expect to happen when you run the command `code.`? Did you mean simply `code` (for Visual Studio Code)?

Comment: In the tutorial they said code . was to open up Visual Studio Code with a particular folder - the first time I tried it opened VSC but did not have the folder in it; second time round nothing came up

Comment: In fairness the tutorial I followed was made 3 years ago, obviously a lot has changed and there were some things I couldn't do but I'm not sure of that would have a large affect on installing this

Comment: `code .` opens VS Code in the current working directory - if you haven't created a subfolder there (either through File Explorer or with `mkdir <dirname>`) it wouldn't show up there.

Answer (score 0):

it's simple , on command prompt type:

> cd c:\users\user\hello-world

then type:

> ng serve

and after complete serve on browser type this address:

> localhost:4200

welcome to angular ;)